# Downloadable Themes on Android

Tags: android, resources, themes

I am currently investigating the possibility of **adding support to downloadable skins/themes in my application.**
As the res folder cannot be changed in runtime, I am looking for alternatives and already arrived to some conclusions.

I tried to have 2 apps with the main app access resources from the auxiliary one (that has different styles/layouts/themes with matching names) with methods as:

```
Resources res = getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication("org.example.foo");
res.getIdentifier("AnotherTheme", "style", "org.example.foo");
```

or

```
Context externalContext = createPackageContext("org.example.foo", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
Theme externalTheme = externalContext.getTheme();
getTheme().setTo(externalTheme);
```

among other methods related to this kind of "remote" loading. However **none of this worked**.

It seems that loading resources from another package only works for "direct" resources like drawables or strings.
My theory is that styles and themes work with references and as such the system fails to apply those references on the current Context.

**The question is: can this be done with this approach or with a similar one?**

After this, there is the other method... Bypass Android Resource manager entirely and manage everything programatically.
My main concern here is performance, so does anyone know what kind of optimizations are done with the resources pre-compiling on Android apps? Or during runtime?

Comment: do you have any update on this, NeTeInStEiN?

Comment: Currently i think this still remains true, which means there isn't really a good way to have downloadable themes without affecting performance IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I am starting a project with a similar feature soon. I have been playing around with changing colors and drawables programmatically and, although it is a fiddle, it works well.

I can't really comment on performance because my research app was small. I had it successfully working with layout backgrounds, button states and spinner/listview backgrounds with states. Would be interested in any experiences with programmatically set backgrounds and large listviews!